# Get single property array from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this array of objects and I want to get all the `controls` from this to another array:

```
this.formModel = {
    sections: [
        {
            title: 'Section 01',
            controls: [
                new FormControlInput({
                    key: 'name 01',
                    label: 'Name 01'
                }),
                new FormControlSelect({
                    key: 'abc',
                    label: 'Abc'
                })
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Section 02',
            controls: [
                new FormControlInput({
                    key: 'name 02',
                    label: 'Name 02'
                })
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I am using `map` for this but I am not getting single array, I am getting array of arrays:

```
this.formModel.sections.map(function (x) { return x.controls; })
```

Getting this:

```
[
     {
        [{
            key: 'name 01',
            label: 'Name 01'
        },
        {
            key: 'abc',
            label: 'Abc'
        }]
     },
     {
        [{
            key: 'name 02',
            label: 'Name 02'
        }]
     }
]
```

What I want is this:

```
[
    {
        key: 'name 01',
        label: 'Name 01'
    },
    {
        key: 'abc',
        label: 'Abc'
    },
    {
        key: 'name 02',
        label: 'Name 02'
    }       
]
```

Comment: please add `FormControlInput` as well.

Comment: What does `FormControlInput` return?

Comment: Obviously, `FormControlInput` just return an object.

Comment: Yes simple TypeScript class.

Comment: @Cerbrus I commented when it wasn't clear.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Look at his output examples. They're just objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to flatten the hierarchy

```
formModel.sections
  .map(x =>  x.controls)
  .reduce((prev, current) => prev.concat(current), [])
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to flatten your array after mapping:

```js
var obj = {
  sections: [{
      title: 'Section 01',
      controls: [
        { key: 'name 01', label: 'Name 01' },
        { key: 'abc', label: 'Abc' }
      ]
    }, {
      title: 'Section 02',
      controls: [
        { key: 'name 02', label: 'Name 02' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var mapped = obj.sections.map(function (x) { return x.controls; });
var flattened = [].concat.apply([], mapped);
console.log(flattened);
```

To simplify your example:

```js
// This is your structure:
var sections= [{
      controls: [{}, {}] // C1
    }, {
      controls: [{}]     // C2
    }
];

// With the map, grabbing each `controls` property, and using that as an entry in your array:
var mapped = sections.map(function (x) { return x.controls; });
console.log(mapped);
// [[{},{}],[{}]]
//  ^ C1    ^ C2

// We need to remove that extra layer of arrays:
var flattened = [].concat.apply([], mapped);
console.log(flattened);
```

Comment: But why this is happening?

Comment: `controls` is an array of objects. I've added a simplified example. I hope this makes it a little easier to visualize what's happening.

Comment: I think what's missing is an explanation  of  `Array.prototype.apply`, and how it takes arguments as an array.  So in the end, the call becomes something similar to spreading the mapped array, like so: `var flattened = Array.prototype.concat([], ...mapped)`.

Comment: @jonahe: I'm pretty sure the _"Why is this happening"_ is referring the the nested arrays.

Comment: Ah, maybe..  But then wouldn't this question have been.. in the question, instead of in this comment? (And in no other comments to any other answers). Either way, ff `.map` is unclear to OP, then I guess `[].concat.apply([], mapped)` wouldn't be obvious either.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` instead of `map`:

```js
let formModel = {
    sections: [
        {
            title: 'Section 01',
            controls: [
                {
                    key: 'name 01',
                    label: 'Name 01'
                },
                {
                    key: 'abc',
                    label: 'Abc'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Section 02',
            controls: [
                {
                    key: 'name 02',
                    label: 'Name 02'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

let result = formModel.sections.reduce((res, section) => {
 return res = res.concat(section.controls); 
}, []);

console.log(result);
```